# Find coordinates inside polygon using Ruby

Tags: ruby, gis

How can I determine if coordinate point lies within a polygon using Ruby?

Comment: The same way you could in any language?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Point in Polygon aka hit test](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/217578/point-in-polygon-aka-hit-test)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Jake Scruggs has an entry on the matter [here](http://jakescruggs.blogspot.com/2009/07/point-inside-polygon-in-ruby.html). The theory behind is the classic [odd/even ray intersection](http://web.archive.org/web/20120818180531/http://paulbourke.net/geometry/insidepoly/), and it has been tackled at SO at least [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/217578/point-in-polygon-aka-hit-test).

Comment: This answers the question as asked and is a really cool answer. I possibly should have inquired about the best gem/library.